# Fiddler not capturing Talend tRestClient calls

Tags: talend, fiddler

I am using tRestClient component in my Talend job to call a REST API. The REST API call is working fine when sent through Postman. But it is giving 500-Internal Server Error when executed through Talend job.

I want to investigate it further using Fiddler. Is there any special setting I need to do in Fiddler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a tSetProxy before the tRestClient, and set your fiddler proxy address and port so that traffic goes through Fiddler.
For me it's localhost 8888.